# How to know the next value of a sequence without increasing it?

Tags: sql-server

There is no next_value column on `sys_sequences`, so you need to get the `current_value` and increment it.

```
select convert(int, current_value) + 1 as next_value
from sys.sequences
where name = 'my_sequence'
```

The problem appears when you restart a sequence, the previous query will return a wrong value.

```
alter sequence my_sequence restart with 100;

select convert(int, current_value) + 1 as next_value
from sys.sequences
where name = 'my_sequence'
```

This is going to return 101 instead of the real next value, which is 100.

Do you know of a reliable way to calculate the next value of a sequence ?

Comment: Why do you need to know what the next value is going to be before you use it anyway? If you have this much reliance on it I would be wary that you have a race condition in your code anyway.

Comment: You can know the **current** value of a sequence (by inspecting the `sys.sequences` catalog view), but you can never reliably know the **next value** that will be handed out - you must call `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR ...` in order to actually get the next value - there's no "peeking" ahead of time

Comment: @SeanLange I use sequences to generate bill numbers, and I want to inform the users of the last value/next value at a billing sequence. But on SQL Server I can't know if current_value is in fact the last value or the next value that will be used on that sequence.

Comment: You can't be sure that the value you might see would be correct anyway because what you are describing is a setup for a race condition. If you said that 101 would be the next value but you don't actually use that value then 101 could very easily be consumed by another process while you are deciding if you want to use it or not.

Comment: If you have to know the value, you could insert a dummy row into the table and get the value, then update instead of insert, an ugly hack but the only way you can be sure of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know of a reliable way to calculate the next value of a sequence ?

As far as I can tell, you are correct. One possible workaround would be to set your restart value one less than what you want, and use up the first value with a dummy variable after your `restart`.

```
create sequence my_sequence as int start with 1;
alter sequence my_sequence restart with 99;
declare @dummy int = next value for my_sequence;

select convert(int, s.current_value) + convert(int,s.increment) as next_value
from sys.sequences s
where s.name = 'my_sequence';
```

[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e452ef17f8fe22ff01fd5ee3ebbaf5ee)

But as marc_s points out, there is no reliable "peeking" for the next value.

Comment: I like this workaround, it's simple. I'm going to set it this way, thank you.